# Eroor Using NSPredicate with blocks in Swift "Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nspredicate

I have created a conditional block just to test NSPredicate with Block. This is how I am doing it,

[image]

If you could guide me here, it would be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is CellInfo? Also, blurry pic = ow, my eyes.

Comment: It's NSObject. @Kreiri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same function signature as NSPredicate needs for the block. In your case you should change your code to:

```
var condblock = {
    (celInfo: AnyObject!, dic : NSDictionary!) -> Bool in
    return true
}
let pred = NSPredicate(block: condblock)
```

Comment: have you tried it? gives the same "could not find overload..." in Xcode6 beta2

Comment: Ah, you also need to use AnyObject! instead of CellInfo! I updated the Answer

Comment: It still throws the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use inline closure and type inference, maybe such bugs are easier to avoid?

```
let pred = NSPredicate { cellInfo, dic in true }
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I don't have Xcode6</sub>